# How to fireLocalNotification based on Internet connection availability in iPhone?

Tags: ios, localnotification

I am writing an IOS application, in which i need to upload some data to server when my application is in background. I thought of using Local notification but , for localNotification only following options are available
fireDate, timeZone,repeatInterval , repeat Calendar
But i have to fire  local notification when internet connection gets activated in device.
Can i achieve this using LocalNotification? how can i do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello RockandRoll, Did you acheive this or not? If yes please share your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using ***reachabilityForInternetConnection*** and ***reachabilityForLocalWifi*** you can get notified of it. But in real world scenario it doesn't work so efficiently. Sometimes it doesn't.
And one more thing if you set a local notification in your app for the background state then it will be active for little time after that your app will come into suspended state, where code doesn't execute.
But you can set timer by *pinging to google or your server* OR *by checking for reachability*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the reachability.  If it is not the value you desire, then you need to register for notification when reachability changes.  When that changes to ReachableViaWiFi you should remove the registered notification and fire your action.

Look at the reachability example project in the docs.  Add reachability.[mh] to your project.

Comment: Hello KHansen, Reachability gives me the status of connection, but how to make my app launch, or execute some code in background based on status of connection. i tried Reachability sample and it works fine, but not getting how to execute code when app is in background, when internet status  get changes from NotReachable to ReachableviaWIFI or ReachableWViaWWAN?